# Solve matrix exponential power series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

The matrix exponential is defined as

$$ e^A  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} A^n  $$

However I would like to solve something similar:

$$ B = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} A^{n-1}  $$
(**NOTE: starting index and the power**)

I can transform that into

$$ B = A^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} A^{n} -I = A^{-1} \left(e^A - I \right) $$

---

- That works. But when $A^{-1}$ does not exist ($A$ is not invertible) it does not work.
- Is it possible to make it work for general $A$? Has anyone thoughts on that? Thanks.

Comment: A generic matrix is invertible and the right and side exists. So if you should be unlucky and have a $B$ with $\det B =0$, then you simply add $\epsilon I$ to $B$ calculate the right hand side and then let $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your question asks how to apply the function $(e^x-1)/x$ to a matrix. One way to do it is using the integral representation
$$\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\int_0^1 e^{tx}\ dt.$$
Thus we can define $B$ to be
$$
B:=\int_0^1 e^{tA}\ dt.
$$
Since you already know what the matrix exponential is, this expression makes sense: the integral of a matrix is computed by taking the integral of each of its entries.

Note also that this coincides with the power series definition you have written, since $$\int_0^1 \frac{(tA)^{n}}{n!}\ dt=\frac{A^{n}}{(n+1)!}.$$

Comment: That seems good, but I don't quite understand how I can get a feasible solution for $B$ from that...

Comment: The feasible solution for $B$ is $\int_0^1 e^{tA}\ dt$. For any matrix, this is a well-defined quantity that is straightforward to compute.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix B is in literature called phi-function $\varphi_1$. The power series expansion of the general form is
\begin{align}
   \varphi_k (A) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{(n+k)!}
\end{align}
If an approximate solution is sufficient a Pade approximation $\varphi_1(A) \approx (1-A/2)^{-1}$ would be a possible solution.